# reduce list of integers/range of integers in scala

Tags: scala, scala-2.8, scala-collections

Total newbie question here...Today while trying to calculate sum of a list of integers(actually BitSet), I ran into overflow scenarios and noticed that the return type of(sum/product) is Int. Are there any methods in Range/List to sum up or say multiply all values to Long?

```
val x = 1 to Integer.MaxValue
println(x.sum) //prints -1453759936
```

thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Convert the elements to Long (or BigInt should that go that far) while summing:

```
x.view.map(_.toLong).sum
```

You can also go back to fold

```
x.foldLeft(0L)(_ + _)
```

(Note: should you sum over a range, maybe it would be better do a little math, but I understand that is not what you did in fact)

Answer (score 3):

Compare:

```
>> val x = 1 to Int.MaxValue
x: scala.collection.immutable.Range.Inclusive with scala.collection.immutable.Range.ByOne = Range(...)
```

With:

```
>> val x = 1L to Int.MaxValue
x: scala.collection.immutable.NumericRange.Inclusive[Long] = NumericRange(...)
```

Note that the first uses `Int.to`, and the latter used `Long.to` (where Int.MaxValue is up-converted automatically). Of course, the sum of a consecutive integer sequence has a very nice discrete formula :)

Happy coding.

Comment: Have a look at https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-4658 for the yet-to-come improvement. :-)

Comment: @soc Very nice that it's making it std :)

Answer (score 2):

This isn't very efficient, but the easiest way:

```
val x = 1L to Int.MaxValue
println(x.sum) //prints 2305843008139952128
```

If you need x to contain Ints rather than Longs, you can do

```
val x = 1 to Int.MaxValue
println(x.foldLeft(0L)(_+_))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Range.Long(1, Int.MaxValue, 1).sum
```